# Recent update in ubuntu 14.04 resulted in my external monitor being unable to go above 1024x768 without being met with a black screen/no signal

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, resolution, hdmi

This is all through HDMI. I cannot go above 1024x768 or I get a black screen / no signal.  This means anywhere between 1152x864 and 1920x1080 (which is what I had been set at before the issue).  1024x768 isn't exactly pretty to look at - lines and graphical glitches all over the place. 800x600 and 720x576 work as well, again with the same graphical errors.

I suppose a good start is xrandr at 1920x1080:

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3286 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1366x768+1920+312 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768       60.0*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

HDMI1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   50.0     50.0     50.0     59.9  
   1920x1080i     60.1     50.0     60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x800       59.9  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9  
   1024x768       70.1     60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x480        60.0     59.9  
   640x480        66.7     60.0     59.9  
   720x400        70.1  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

xrandr sees it, the screen display sees it - hell, if I open up a workspace I can see the windows being opened there (I have to move them back to my laptop display).  No clue what the issue could be. Maybe xorg.conf?  It's blank at the moment - might I have to add something in?

As for my card - intel 4000 and nvida 630m.